# Getting invalid regular expression but functions correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angular, regex, typescript

I have an html input box where I use the angular directive [pattern]="emailPattern";
and have email pattern defined in my component file as:

```
public emailPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$";
```

But when I check the dev tools console on chrome I see this error:

```
Pattern attribute value ^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid Regular Expression: /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/v Invalid character in character class.
```

Comment: That string does not throw an exception. How exactly are you using it?

Comment: like this in the html: <input id="emailinput" [(ngModel)]"emailAddress" maInput ngmodel required #emailinput="ngModel" [pattern]="emailPattern">

Comment: I'm not seeing an error either, but you can just use <input ... email required> "email" will set the built-in email validator: https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator